# NullPointerException when using Slider.setShowTickLabels method in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

`NullPointerException` when using `Slider.setShowTickLabels` method.

I'm using **JavaFX SDK 17.0.1** and **JDK 11.0.13.8**

Windows 10

```
public void start(Stage window) {
    BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();

    Slider slider = new Slider(0, 100, 0);
    slider.setShowTickMarks(true);
//        slider.setShowTickLabels(true);

    pane.setCenter(slider);

    Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
    window.setScene(scene);
    window.setTitle("Application");
    window.show();
}
```

Output when `slider.setShowTickLabels(true)` is commented out.

[image]

Getting an exception when including the same method.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.font.directwrite.DWGlyph.createBitmap(DWGlyph.java:287)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.font.directwrite.DWGlyph.getCachedBitmap(DWGlyph.java:273)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.font.directwrite.DWGlyph.getD2DMask(DWGlyph.java:167)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.font.directwrite.DWGlyph.getPixelData(DWGlyph.java:352)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.prism.impl.GlyphCache.getCachedGlyph(GlyphCache.java:258)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.prism.impl.GlyphCache.render(GlyphCache.java:148)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.prism.impl.ps.BaseShaderGraphics.drawString(BaseShaderGraphics.java:2101)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGText.renderText(NGText.java:312)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGText.renderContent2D(NGText.java:270)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGShape.renderContent(NGShape.java:261)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:2072)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.render(NGNode.java:1964)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGGroup.renderContent(NGGroup.java:270)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion.renderContent(NGRegion.java:578)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:2072)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.render(NGNode.java:1964)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGGroup.renderContent(NGGroup.java:270)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion.renderContent(NGRegion.java:578)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:2072)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.render(NGNode.java:1964)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGGroup.renderContent(NGGroup.java:270)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion.renderContent(NGRegion.java:578)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:2072)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.render(NGNode.java:1964)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.ViewPainter.doPaint(ViewPainter.java:479)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.ViewPainter.paintImpl(ViewPainter.java:328)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.PresentingPainter.run(PresentingPainter.java:91)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.RenderJob.run(RenderJob.java:58)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:125)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Can you run your app with `java -Djavafx.verbose=true -Dprism.verbose=true` ... and edit the question to include the output formatted as code?

Comment: cannot reproduce ..

Comment: I had not configured the environment variables correctly. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out, I had not included the JavaFX SDK path correctly in the environment variables.
Had the path pointing to the `\bin` folder, instead of `\lib`.